# How to add a string in front of each array

Tags: php

I want to produce a string like this from an array:

```
omc_playroom.id,omc_playroom.name,omc_playroom.parentid,
omc_playroom.status,omc_playroom.table_id,omc_playroom.lang_id
```

I tried this, but it adds omc_playroom only for the first one.

```
$fields = array('id, name, parentid, status, table_id, lang_id');
$module ='playroom';
$playrooms = getAll($fields, $module);
echo $playrooms;

function getAll($fields, $module){
    $string = '';
    $module_table = 'omc_' . $module;
    foreach ($fields as $field){
       $string .= ",$module_table.$field";
    }
    $string = substr($string, 1); // Remove leading ","
    return $string;
}
```

This produces:

```
 omc_playroom.id,name,parentid,status,table_id,lang_id
```

How can I add omc_playroom in front of each item?

Answer (score 2):

Well, first, you don't really have an array of items : all you items are in a single string, which is the only element of your `$fields` array.

Let's extract that item, and remove the spaces that are sometimes present after the `','` separator :

```
$fields = array('id, name,parentid,status,table_id,lang_id');
$str = $fields[0];
$str = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
```

Now, we split the `$str` string, using `','` as a separator :

```
$items = explode(',', $str);
```

And loop over the resulting array, adding the prefix to each element :

```
foreach ($items as & $item) {
    $item = 'omc_' . $item;
}
```

Finally, we can implode those elements back together, and echo the result :

```
$new_str = implode(',', $items);
echo $new_str;
```

And we get :

```
omc_id,omc_name,omc_parentid,omc_status,omc_table_id,omc_lang_id
```

Which seems to be what you expected.

---

But, of couse, if your `$fields` variable did indeed contain a real proper array :

```
$fields = array('id', 'name', 'parentid', 'status', 'table_id', 'lang_id');
```

Things would have been so much easier : you'd just have to loop over that array :

```
$fields = array('id', 'name', 'parentid', 'status', 'table_id', 'lang_id');
foreach ($fields as & $field) {
    $field = 'omc_' . $field;
}
var_dump($fields);
```

And you'd get :

```
array
  0 => string 'omc_id' (length=6)
  1 => string 'omc_name' (length=8)
  2 => string 'omc_parentid' (length=12)
  3 => string 'omc_status' (length=10)
  4 => string 'omc_table_id' (length=12)
  5 => &string 'omc_lang_id' (length=11)
```

Comment: Also note that probably not experienced developer could have issues with working with `$field` variable that still points to the last item after the loop.

Comment: true ; adding `unset($field);` after the `foreach` loop might be a good idea, to avoid any problem later.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, as you currntly have an array with only ONE element.

```
$fields = array('id', 'name', 'parentid', 'status', 'table_id', 'lang_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a "variable delimiter", `preg_replace()` can do this in just one step.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a3d330a6a6fb3f16c5ee6c61c19814d0cdf7d324))

```
$fields=['id, name,parentid,status,table_id,lang_id'];
$module='playroom';
$module_table='omc_'.$module;

echo preg_replace('/^|,\K ?/',"$module_table.",$fields[0]);
//  start of string-^
//              OR---^
//                    ^^^^^-match comma, restart match, then match optional space
```

Output:

```
omc_playroom.id,omc_playroom.name,omc_playroom.parentid,omc_playroom.status,omc_playroom.table_id,omc_playroom.lang_id
```